# Installing nodeos error: OpenSSL must be configured to support threads

Tags: nodeos

While I am building the nodeos source code in my computer, I get an error

```
" .../src/crypto/aes/cpp:14:3: error:
 "OpenSSL must be configured to support threads"
```

and the build stops.

I referenced [this on GitHub](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/wiki/Local-Environment/10b1474d44e1812c319009edb0aca3fe1e2b7e90.).

How can I solve this problem?

My computer has Ubuntu 16.04, the disk space is 249GB and the OpenSSL version is 1.1.0i.